# Learning basic impact mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, field-theory, continuum-mechanics

Now I know a lot about continuum mechanics, but I still don't know why a pulse impact load damages a solid material a lot more than a constant load (i.e. a loading that varies nothing or slowly with time). What are the fundamental equations to analyze this fact? I need the equations of elasticity theory in the bulk

$ \partial_{t}(\rho\partial_{t} \vec{x}) + div(\rho \partial_{t} \vec{x} \otimes \partial_{t} \vec{x}) = div \sigma+f$

$\sigma_{ij} = c_{ijkl}E_{kl}$

with mass density $\rho$, elasticity constants $c_{ijkl}$, volume force density $f$, stress tensor $\sigma$ and Cauchy-Green strain tensor $E_{kl}$. 
Now assume that two bodies $\Omega_1,\Omega_2$ of different material properties, initial velocities (one body is resting at the beginning) and different form collide. Do I need additionally the jump condition

$[(\rho \partial_{t} \vec{x} \otimes \partial_{t} \vec{x}-\sigma)\vec{n}]_- = [(\rho \partial_{t} \vec{x} \otimes \partial_{t} \vec{x}-\sigma)\vec{n}]_+$

on the collision region of body 1 denoted by + and collision region of body 2 denoted by - ?
Is there any research literature explaining this?

Comment: Hint: An impact sets a stress wave, and the strains around the pulse are higher than the steady state solution.

Comment: During the collision, acceleration described by the first term on the left hand side of the equation becomes very large, and this strongly affects the stress.  You need to carry out the detailed calculation on the very small time scale that applies during the collision.

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you answer a simplified version of your problem first? Let us suppose you have a piece of thread and you suspend some weight through it, you will find that you can suspend a good amount of weight from it without it snapping. But now if you remove weight and jerk the wire, you will be surprised it breaks quite easily. The intuitive explanation is simple enough, a constant load allows the force to transmitted to all of wire, but a jerk put concentrated force at one particular point that results in the snapping of thread.